# What do different components in OhMyPosh indicate?

Tags: bash, oh-my-posh

I recently installed Oh My Posh and was looking through the [documentation](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/) to see what the different parts in the prompt indicate.

[image]

Through some experiments, so far I have concluded:

root - User name
HelloGitty - Current folder
Github symbol - Clickable link to the origin on GitHub
line and arrow - Branch
Feature3 - Name of the currently checked out branch
3 lines equal sign aka hamburger - No commits pending to push to origin.
Notepad + pen + Question mark followed by a number - Number of untracked files
Checked box followed by number - Number of tracked files
Lightning strike - ?
Blue tick at the end - Last command's exit code. 0: Blue tick, non-zero: red cross.

Wondering what does the lightning strike indicate? Does not look like "power connected to laptop"?
Does my understanding of other components look correct?

Comment: For questions about using and configuring UNIX tools / libraries / &c others wrote, as opposed to writing software, consider [unix.se]

Answer (score 0):

The lightning strike is indicating you are an admin/root user. See the [docs](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/root) for that specific segment.